# sleep() and time() not functioning as expected inside for loop

Tags: c, time, sleep, time.h, unistd.h

I'm trying to create an array of `tm` struct pointers, with each struct having a `tm_sec` value 2 seconds larger than the previous one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* sleep() */

int main(signed int argc, char **argv) {
    struct tm *collection[5];

    for(struct tm **p = collection; p < collection + 5; p += 1) {
        sleep(2);
        const time_t timeNow = time(NULL);
        *p = gmtime(&timeNow);
    }

    for(struct tm **p = collection; p < collection + 5; p += 1) {
        if(p != collection + 4) {
            puts((**p).tm_sec == (**(p + 1)).tm_sec ? "equal" : "not equal");
        }

        puts(asctime(*p));
    }
}
```

Execution lasts around 10 seconds, which seems fine, but the resulting output is:

```
equal
Sat Jul 28 01:42:15 2018
equal
Sat Jul 28 01:42:15 2018    
equal
Sat Jul 28 01:42:15 2018    
equal
Sat Jul 28 01:42:15 2018    
Sat Jul 28 01:42:15 2018
```

Compiled with GCC 7.3.0 on linux64. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

note: Initially I didn't have the first `for` loop sleep on the insertion of the first element, but I removed it here for simplicity's sake. It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The returned pointer from `gmtime` is to a static buffer; see the man page.

Comment: @o11c Thanks, I replaced it with `gmtime_r`: `gmtime_r(&timeNow, *p)`, but for some reason it segfaults after the first 2 seconds..

Comment: No need to use an array of pointers, just use an array of structs.

Comment: @o11c Yeah... thanks!

Comment: OT: when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `if(p != collection + 4)`  this is using the pointer + value feature, where the 'value' (times the size of what the pointer points to) is what is actually added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page:

> POSIX.1-2001 says: "The asctime(), ctime(), gmtime(), and localtime() functions shall return values in one of two static objects: a broken-down time structure and an array of type char.  Execution  of  any  of  the functions may overwrite the information returned in either of these objects by any of the other functions."  This can occur in the glibc implementation.

For single-threaded programs, simply dereference the pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* sleep() */

int main(signed int argc, char **argv) {
    struct tm collection[5];

    for (struct tm *p = collection; p < collection + 5; p++) {
        sleep(2);
        const time_t timeNow = time(NULL);
        *p = *gmtime(&timeNow);
    }

    for(struct tm *p = collection; p < collection + 5; p++) {
        if(p != collection + 4) {
            puts((*p).tm_sec == (*(p + 1)).tm_sec ? "equal" : "not equal");
        }

        puts(asctime(p));
    }
}
```

For multi-threaded programs, you'll need to use `gmtime_r` and `asctime_r`