# Result of time() not updated after sleep()

Tags: c, sleep, time.h

I'm trying to pause my program for 1 second, and check the system time after that (I'm on Linux)

This is my testing program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *time_now = localtime(&now);
    printf("now: %d-%d\n", time_now->tm_min, time_now->tm_sec);

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 5; i++) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    // This printf result is not as expected
    printf("now: %d-%d\n", time_now->tm_min, time_now->tm_sec);

    return 0;
}
```

The expected result is that the second `printf` would print +5 seconds. Instead, it prints the same time/seconds as the first `printf`.

I've found (maybe) the same problem posted here, but it doesn't seem to work:
[sleep() and time() not functioning as expected inside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567384/13108055).

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is printing the original `*time_now` values - as expected.

Simply read time again to use new values.

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *time_now = localtime(&now);
printf("now: %d-%d\n", time_now->tm_min, time_now->tm_sec);

int i = 0;
for (; i < 5; i++) {
    sleep(1);
}

// Add
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *time_now = localtime(&now);

printf("now: %d-%d\n", time_now->tm_min, time_now->tm_sec);
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I thought the value is updated in real-time every time we grab the value..

Comment: @easyGram , the value **is** updated every time you grab the time with `time(NULL)`, yet original code did that only once - before the 5 second delay - the value being `now` and not the `struct tm` pointer to by `time_now`.